# All icons disappear except for the first five from google maps after having been placed on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a webpage with a google map. I use javascript to place markers on the map based on the address that come from a json file. There are 7 addresses in the json file.

When the map loads I see all 7 icons on the map but they disappear right away and then the map is resized with the bounding box.

Is my code wrong or is there a limit on the number icons I can have on the map.  No matter how many addresses are looked up, it always keeps 5 icons on the map. All others are removed.  I doubt that there is a limit because I've seen maps with hundreds of icons.

I do use a different icon for each address.  So I removed the custom icons and used the standard ones provided by Google.  Same problem.  So, it seems to be in the code.  Help anyone.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

var addresses = [];
var address, company;
var geocoder, marker, thumbtack;

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    

// Set map options
    var options = {
    zoom:11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
};

// Create the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng),
    title: "Your Zip Code"
});
//bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng));

    // Get the data
    // var listing is already set in footer.php
    processFile(listings);

function processFile(listings) {
        $.each(listings,function(business, info) {
            address = info[2];
            company = info[0];
            thumbtack = info[4];
            getCoordinates(address, company, thumbtack);
        });
    }


    function getCoordinates(address, company, thumbtack) {
    var counter = 0;
            // Check to see if we already have a geocoded object.  If not we create one.
    if(!geocoder) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    }

    // Create a GeocoderRequest object
    var geocoderRequest = {
        address: address
    }

    // Making the geocode request and adding marker
    geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {
        // Check if status is OK before proceding
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            addresses.push(results[0].geometry.location);
            counter++;
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: company,
                //icon: "http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker" + thumbtack + ".png"
                                    icon: thumbtack
            });
            //bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

            // Adjusting the map to new bounding box
                            //map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }

    });

};
```

});

Comment: Have you tried different addresses?  It sounds like you are starting off zoomed in and can see 7 distinct markers.  Are they so close together that when you zoom out they then appear as one?

Comment: Looks fine, but we'll need to see the rest of your code, or a link to a demo would be ideal.

Comment: what does the `counter` variable do and what is it set to?

Comment: Agree with Pete.  Also, if the 7 addresses are static, why not geocode them using the web service, temporarily cache the relevant info server side, and then render the markers during initial load...it will save your users time...

Comment: Here is a link to the result.

http://www.blacktiehomeservices.com/view/index.php?action=zip_search&searchType=Air+Conditioning+%26+Heating&zipSearch=32714

Comment: Disregard counter; it was to retrieve a marker with a different number for each address.  I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you should only ever see one marker at a time.  I suggest adding a createMarker function that can use function closure to create 7 markers.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map1.html) using a createMarker function.